# Security filtering entity collection with jax-rs and jersey

Tags: filter, jax-rs, entity

I've been looking around on how to filter results based on certain security roles. I've been looking at filters but this just seems to filter out certain fields rather than the complete entity itself. Let me try to explain what I need. Lets say I have 2 entity classes:

```
public class Project {

   private Long id;

   private String name;

   private String description;

   // getters and setters
}


public class User {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    // getters and setters
}
```

resource:

```
@Path("projects")
@Produces("application/json") 
public class ProjectsResource {

    @GET
    public List<Project> getProjects() {
        return getDetailedProjects();
    }
}
```

Also I have 2 companies, each with their own projects. For convenience lets call them company A and company B.

What I would like to achieve is that 3 users all using this same resource get different results based on their security role.

User 1: the Super user, should get everything

User 2: manager for company A, should only get projects for company A

User 3: manager for company B, should only get projects for company B

How should I go about doing this? It just doesn't seem right to do this filtering in each resource.

I'm using jax-rs, with role based security. Users are linked to a role which grants them access to projects for a specific company.

Comment: You should adapt the title to clearly show that this question is related to jax rs , jersey and security

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to parameterize your `getDetailedProjects`method with the accessing user.

To achieve that you can inject the jersey `SecurityContext`into your Resource like so (from [jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html)):

```
@Path("basket")
public ShoppingBasketResource get(@Context SecurityContext sc) {
    if (sc.isUserInRole("PreferredCustomer") {
        return new PreferredCustomerShoppingBasketResource();
    } else {
        return new ShoppingBasketResource();
    }
}
```

The `securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName()`method will allow you to get hold of the requesting user and map that to a method parameter (or use it plain).

Comment: I know the role the user has, that is not my problem. Is this the only way to achieve this? This would mean, that I should implement security logic in every resource itself. I thought it would be more "java" to implement some kind of entity filter. I was also considering extending the entity class and altering the get project method if that is even possible. It just seems much easier that way for a complex application.

Comment: Mixing security with business logic is definitely not nice and there are many ways to realize *Multi tenancy* with other ways. What do you mean with "entity filter" ? You could move the above described logic to a filter but somehow the resource will have to know which projects to load.

Comment: I was thinking, that for every request, the resource should be aware of the user requesting it and check the permissions. Then we know the company the user and the corresponding projects the user has access to. The filter could then go through the result set to filter out projects for another company. But that is after the fact and could take a long time. It would be better to be able to modify the query itself.

Comment: Somehow you have to get a string that identifies the requesting user to the database to query accordingly. An often used approach is using the tenant key as first part of the resource path. Like @Path("{company}/projects") and check (in a filter) if the requesting user is really allow to see that url. This is also a good way towards a restful resource design/hierarchy.

Comment: I have a request filter, so that part would be simple. In this example it is straight forward, just get the projects you need. The application for which I will be using this, are webshops, we have 10 webshops, all placing orders for different products, with different customers, coupons, tax rates, prices, ... . All starting with the company (franchise taker). It seems unsecure to leave all these relationships "unmanaged". I would like a by enitty aproach, where I overwrite the get method so at every turn I can be sure only correct data is returned to the specific user. Same goes for updates.

Comment: Maybe you should expand your question and elaborate on "relationships unmanaged" and "where I overwrite the get method so at every turn I can be sure only correct data is returned ". An URI-Space that (in a way) resembles the domain model is definitely not uncommon.

Comment: Perhaps it is more a design pattern question. I would like to discus further but I don't have enough reputation to chat with you.

Comment: Just reformulate your question or open another one. IMO you should check a "Multitenancy with REST" search